# Error in collection record update Magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection

I have a custom collection I wanted to update a record. I want to do this as below:

```
foreach ($creditDetails as $Card) { 

        echo $Card->getRedeemAmount();
        $Card->setRedeemAmount(44);
        echo $Card->getRedeemAmount();
        //exit;
        $Card->save();
        exit;
```

but Card is not getting save. Initially it was working but I don't know what problem has occurred now. Please a suggest solution.

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: yes by loading model it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should load your record which you want to update. Then, you can update record like this :

```
$creditDetailsObject = $this->creditDetailsFactory->create()->load(1); //Load particular data which you want to update
foreach ($creditDetails as $Card) { 
    $creditDetailsObject->setRedeemAmount(44); //set value in object which you want to update
    $creditDetailsObject->save();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to load model while updating data.

code as below:

```
foreach ($creditDetails as $Card) { 
        $cardModel = $this->cardFactory->create()->load($cardId);
        $cardModel->setRedeemAmount(44);
        $cardModel->save();
}
```

- In above code **$this->cardFactory** is your model factory you need to
  add dependency in construct
- **$cardId** is your table primary key